# Test for react async action creator - undefined data

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, redux-mock-store

I have the following action and test case - when I run this test(jest) - I am seeing TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined in action creator, not sure what is missing here? I am providing mockData that is expected. is it because there is an async nested here? but i am using `.then but it still fails.

```
Action creator:

    export const getUser = ({
      uname,
      apiendpoint,
    }) => {
      const arguments = {};


      return async (dispatch) => {
        await axiosHelper({ ---> this will return axios.get
          arguments,
          path: `${apiendpoint}/${uname}`,
          dispatch,
        }).then(async ({ data, headers }) => { -- getting error at this line.
          dispatch({ type: GET_USER, payload: data });
          dispatch({ type: GET_NUMBEROFUSERS, payload: headers });
        });
      };
    };

Test:

    describe('Get User Action', () => {
      let store;
      const middlewares = [thunk];
      const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
      beforeEach(() => {
        store = mockStore({
          data: [],
        });
      });

      afterEach(() => {
        fetchMock.reset();
        fetchMock.restore();
      })

       const arguments = {
        uname: 'user123',
        apiendpoint: 'test',
      };
      const url = 'https://www.localhost.com/blah/blah';

      it('should get a User', () => {
        fetchMock
          .getOnce(url, {
            data: mockData, -->external mock js file with user data {}
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
          });

        const expectedActions = [
          {
            type: 'GET_USER',
            data: mockData
          },
          { type: 'GET_NUMBEROFUSERS' }
        ];


        return store.dispatch(actions.getUser(arguments)).then(() => {
          expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
        });

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `await` AND `then` on the same function (`axiosHelper` for example).

This is wrong usage and will lead to many errors of `undefined`.
You either use a callback-function **or** a `.then()` **or** an `await` but not 2 or all of them.

I recommend to watch some tutorials/explanations about async/await because it's really important to understand what a Promise is.

What's happening in your cas is that `axiosHelper` is executed 2 times, because if it's finished the `then`-part will fire up but at the exactly same time (because it's async) the `await` finishes and code-execution continues the parent flow. This brings up race-conditions and, as i said, will lead to `undefined` because you are executing the same logic twice or more.